# Encountering a problem with Camera Tracking

Tags: camera, video, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I'm new to Blender

I'm trying to do some camera tracking on my 2013 MacBook Air (4GB RAM, 256GB SSD) running Blender 2.79.

I'm following [BlenderGuru's tutorial](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-camera-tracking). After setting around nine tracking points in high-contrast areas, when I hit **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>**, the progress bar shows up, but even after 30 minutes it simply lingers at 0 percent without changing. When I cancel the job, Blender freezes and I have to force quit the program.

What am I doing wrong, or is my computer unable handle the load?

Thanks in advance.

PS In order to cache the video, I have allocated 2.4GB of my RAM. Here's a screenshot of my other settings:
[image: PatternSize:10,SearchSize:30,Motion:Perspective,Match:PreviousFrame,Prepass:Yes,Normalize:No,UseMask:No,Correlation:0.75,FramesLimit:0,Margin:5px,Weight:1]

Comment: How long is your input sequence? Do you load in a video, or an image sequence? Did you try tracking the points one by one? I'd suggest you set your trackers to Location, Perspective is slow and a bit wonky.

Comment: My input sequence is actually over 300 frames long; I just shortened it by setting the start frame to 100 and the end frame to 210. I load a video recorded on a camera (In case it's important, it's a .MOV file). I tried tracking one-by-one, but the same problem arose, even after deleting the perspective markers and replacing them with location.

Comment: Track one point at the time one tracker might fail for a different reason than another.  When the tracker stops it is usually because it cannot find a match within the search box. You can then try to have a larger search area for that particular tracker. If that doesn't work try tracking with a different option in the motion settings.

Comment: 300 frames should be no problem. I would suggest to make an image sequence (PNG or similar) from your mov. Some codecs compress by comparing beween several frames, those codecs cause problems for applications that don't necessarily treat videos linearly.

Comment: Questions about motion tracking are very hard to answer without seeing the video you are using and how you set your trackers. Consider uploading your file and video clip. **To learn more about motion tracking please read** [**this link**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332)